# How to ensure data integrity in query results using Prisma when some records are incomplete?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, prisma

I have a `User` model like this:

```
model User {
  id    String   @id @default(uuid())
  email String   @unique
  name  String
  roles String[]

  accounts Account[]
}

model Account {
  /// The provider of the account (eg: discord, local, etc)
  provider AccountProvider
  userId   String

  primary Boolean

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  /// The provider-specific account ID
  providerId String @unique

  // ...
}
```

and my problem is that `User`s can be created by inviting someone (using `email`), but those users will not have `Account`s. My data integrity rules postulate that a valid `User` must have at least *one* `Account` and *exactly one* `primary` `Account`.

Right now I can't enforce this, but I can't simply have these "unfinished" `User`s in a different table, because they have other relations (for example you can add a not-yet-activated user to a `Team`).

How do I ensure that only valid users are included in any query where the `User` table is joined without having to add the `where` condition to all of those queries by hand? Is this possible using `Prisma`?

*Note that this is very similar to using soft delete (`deletedAt: DateTime`). A solution for soft delete would also work here.*